# Android-Youtube Player Api - Switch Videos?

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api

How i can use android player api switced videos ?
These are the codes I use, but not the other video.
Android Studio 2.3 usage

```
 lw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            sirax = position;
           oke();

        }
    });


public void oke(){ videoPlayer.initialize(api.api_key,this);}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
 if(!wasRestored)
 {
 switch (sirax)
 {
    case 0:
        player.cueVideo("MHj7ApwQXU0");
        break;
    case 1:
        player.cueVideo("1GX_4PgUhYo");
        break;
  }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is because of your switch code, but try checking the [Episode 12: YouTube It, All Night Long!](http://androiddev101.com/episode-12-youtube-it-all-night-long/) tutorial, this shows how to properly cue videos. You might also try using [`loadVideo()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo(java.lang.String)). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize youtube player just once -Initialize it before listener -

In ItemClickListener create method to switch YouTube videos and in each switch case call pause() then load(), something like this:

```
videoPlayer.initialize(api.api_key,this);
lw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            sirax = position;
           oke();

        }
    });
public void oke(){ 
 switch (sirax) {
    case 0:
        player.loadVideo("MHj7ApwQXU0");
        break;
    case 1:
        player.loadVideo("1GX_4PgUhYo");
        break;
  }}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
 if(!wasRestored)
 {
    player.cueVideo("MHj7ApwQXU0");
  }
```